# ElasticSearch not indexing new mappings on Particular Model Ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

Having a hard time getting elasticsearch to index new mappings that apart of the model

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
  mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :body, type: 'string', analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :status, type: 'string'
    indexes :post_type, type: 'string'
    indexes :genre, type: 'string'
  end
end
```

Above is the Model of a `post`.  The new addition is `genre`.

After adjusting the Model as above what else is needed to get elasticsearch to start displaying results also based on the new attribute.

This is also being called on every save, so there should be no problems in it picking it up

```
def regenerate_index!
  Post.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
  Post.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!
  Post.import
end
```

all index output

```
url 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health index                 pri rep docs.count docs.deleted
store.size pri.store.size
yellow posts                   1   1      10871            0              1.7mb          1.7mb
```

Doing a get on the index seems to have the proper mappings as well

```
{
  "posts": {
    "mappings": {
      "post": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
          "body": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
          },
          "genre": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "post_type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For whatever reason the documents are not adding all the mappings:

```
http://localhost:9200/posts/post/10000
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "posts",
  "_type": "post",
  "_id": "10000",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "body": "*thinks about Frank's birds*\n*sweats*",
    "status": "new"
  }
}
```